# Nexus OSS 3: Avoid download of specific artifacts

Tags: maven, routes, nexus, nexus3

this might be similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948635/how-do-i-configure-routing-in-nexus-oss-3), but might not.

I want to avoid that ANY remote repository (called proxy repository in Nexus) will ever try to download an artifact starting with `my.company`.

I tried using Content selectors, but no luck; it still tried to download this URL: `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/my/company/some/0.1.0/some-0.1.0.pom`.

In Artifactory I can specify exlcudes, and in Nexus 2 there was routing. What can be done about this in Nexus 3?

What I did:

- Created a selector matching path or GroupId
- Created privileges for each remote repository
- Assigned the privileges to a new  role
- no other role  has access to the new role, no user at all has the new role.
- All users can still see and browse central for artifacts `my/company` (if it existed).

Although it seems you NEED this role to read or view artifacts starting with my/company, it does not hinder nexus to try to download them.

Am I correct? Is there anything which can be done?
Why can people still browse that path despite not having this privilege?

Thanks!